# Delete Objects after Saving - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a problem about Delete Object after savings Django
I have model Like:

```
class Reaction(models.Model):
    REACT_TYPES = (
        (LIKE, 'Like'),
        (LOVE, 'Love'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    react_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=REACT_TYPES, default='LIKE')
```

How can I write a `save()`:
When saving, it should remove the available object with **THE SAME user and react_type** or create one if object doesn't exists.

```
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        user = Reaction.objects.filter(user=self.user)
        react_type = Reaction.objects.filter(user=self.react_type)
        # Model delete if exist
        if self.id.exists() & self.react_type.exists() :
            self.Reaction.delete()
        # Model create if not exist
        else :
            self.Reaction.create()
```

Fix with @dirkgroten solution:

```
class ReactionManager(models.Manager):
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        similars = Reaction.objects.filter(user=self.user, react_type=self.react_type)

        if similars.exists():
            print ('exist')
            similars.delete()
        else:
            print ('Not exist')
            similars.create()
    super(Reaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: your requirement is unclear: the only attributes are `user` and `react_type`, why would you delete the object that's already there when saving? Do you want to end up with no object at all?

Comment: Also your code is all over  the place. If you want the objects with same `user` and `react_type`, you should query like this: `similars = Reaction.objects.filter(user=self.user, react_type=self.react_type)`. And then `similars.delete()`. Note that by doing this you're also deleting 'self' if it's already saved (so you might want to add to the above query: `.exclude(id=self.id)`. Finally you don't need to explicitely create a new object, `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` will create the new object for you.

Comment: @dirkgroten I fix this code like you said. Could you check it again please

Comment: It not work correctly. The previous similar was deleted but new one is not!

Comment: @Feed Git  You can check **get_or_create()** method in django. If already exists, **created** returns False otherwise true.

Comment: @VijeshVenugopal Could you give me more details with code please

Comment: First of all, overriding the `save()` method should be done in the `Model` not in the `Manager`. Next, `similars.create()` is wrong you can't create an empty QuerySet. So you should not have `else` clause. Last, your call to `super` is wrongly indented (should be inside the `def save()` method). If you're using python3, remove the arguments (just `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` so you don't have to worry about using the correct class. In your code the class is actually wrong (but correct if you change to the `Model` instead of the `Manager`).

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code. It may help you:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
    similars, created = Reaction.objects.get_or_create(user=self.user, react_type=self.react_type)

    if not created:
        print ('exist')
        similars.delete()
    super(Reaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: still curious what's the purpose of doing this. You're deleting an object to create the exact same object afterwards... if the `Reaction` model has other fields than `user` and `react_type` it might make sense, but this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: In the above code, if the **created** returns False, then only the model object will get deleted. Otherwise, it will remain same.

Comment: I fixed it success in my code below. But I think there are many better solution. Hope you soon!

Answer (score 0):

This code will work ok.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        similars = Reaction.objects.filter(user=self.user, content_type=self.content_type, object_id=self.object_id)
        if similars.exists():
            similars.delete()
            similars.update(user=self.user, react_type=self.react_type)
        else :
            similars.update(user=self.user, react_type=self.react_type)
        super(Reaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```